# An entry widget in tkinter not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm working on a database with a graphical interface, I made an insert and delete method connected to the database, now I'm working on creating a search method but unfortunately not working for an unexpected error. The code Is a little bit long :

```
import sqlite3
from Tkinter import *
global all,root, main_text, num_ent, nom_ent, search_ent

def showall():
    all = True
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'select * from blinta'
    cur.execute(request)
    table = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return table
    con.commit()
    con.close()


def delete():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = ' DELETE FROM blinta WHERE id=?'
    cur.execute(request, (ident.get(),))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.configure(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.configure(state='disabled')
    ident.delete(0,END)


def insert():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'insert into blinta (nom,numero) values(?,?)'
    cur.execute(request, (nom_ent.get(), num_ent.get()))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.config(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.config(state='disabled')
    num_ent.delete(0, END)
    nom_ent.delete(0, END)

def search():
    all=False
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = "select * from blinta where nom = ?"
    noun = search_ent.get()
    args=(noun,)
    cur.execute(request,args)
    selected = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return selected
    con.commit()
    con.close()

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='#D2B024')
root.geometry('450x650+900+0')
root.minsize(450, 650)
root.maxsize(450, 650)
main_text = Text(root, bg='#CBCAC5', fg='black', width=30, height=40, state='normal')
main_text.grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=50, padx=9, pady=3)
main_text.delete(1.0, END)
if all == True :
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
else :
    main_text.insert(1.0, search())
main_text.config(state='disabled')

nomlbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to insert',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=1,column=2)

nom_ent = Entry(root)
nom_ent.grid(row=2, column=2)

num_lbl=Label(root, text='Enter number to insert', bg='#D2B024').grid(row=3, column=2)

num_ent = Entry(root)
num_ent.grid(row=4, column=2)

insert_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='insert', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=insert).grid(row=5, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=50)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=6,column=2)

idlbl=Label(root,text='Enter id to delete',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=7,column=2)
ident=Entry(root)
ident.grid(row=8,column=2)

delete_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='delete', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=delete).grid(row=9, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=10,column=2)

search_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to search',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=11,column=2)

search_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='search', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=search).grid(row=13, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)

global search_ent
search_ent = Entry(root)
search_ent.grid(row=12, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

All the problem is related to the search function where the entry search_ent is not defined and I m sure it is on the global scope
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/asus/Documents/python/Projet/managment system/main.py", line 
70, in <module>
main_text.insert(1.0, search())
File "C:/Users/asus/Documents/python/Projet/managment system/main.py", line 
51, in search
noun = search_ent.get()
NameError: name 'search_ent' is not defined
```

Comment: Put `global search_ent` in the `search` function. *If you need to access and change the value of the global variable from within a function, this permission is granted by the global keyword within the function as well.*

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also post the *full traceback* as well.

Comment: Did you define a button like `Button(..., command=search(), ...)` before `search_ent = Entry(root)`?

Comment: yes, i defined a button of course with a command search, and also tried to declare the global in the beginning of the search function but always the same error.

Comment: You should use `command=search` instead of `command=search()`.

Comment: yeah I made exactly like this, btw I have good knowledge in Tkinter

Comment: So post the *full traceback* as I said in previous comment.

Comment: I will edit the answer

Comment: I posted the full code with the traceback, I hope it is clear

Comment: The traceback shows that the line `main_text.insert(1.0, search())` is causing the error because when `search()` is called by the above line, `search_ent` is not defined yet.  Note that `all` is a built-in function, so `if all == True` will be evaluated as false, so the else block will be executed.

Comment: `table = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')` this line can b replaced to simpler terms, like with indexing u can access each terms and loop through them

Answer (score 1):

you can give your search function an input. global statement is for an outer scope. for example when you want to make a function in another function. you can [check here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php). 
and now about your code. here is a simple way that I have said the idea:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
global all,root, main_text, num_ent, nom_ent, search_ent

def showall():
    all = True
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'select * from blinta'
    cur.execute(request)
    table = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return table
    con.commit()
    con.close()


def delete():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = ' DELETE FROM blinta WHERE id=?'
    cur.execute(request, (ident.get(),))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.configure(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.configure(state='disabled')
    ident.delete(0,END)


def insert():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'insert into blinta (nom,numero) values(?,?)'
    cur.execute(request, (nom_ent.get(), num_ent.get()))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.config(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.config(state='disabled')
    num_ent.delete(0, END)
    nom_ent.delete(0, END)

def search(search_ent):
    all=False
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = "select * from blinta where nom = ?"
    noun = search_ent.get()
    args=(noun,)
    cur.execute(request,args)
    selected = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return selected
    con.commit()
    con.close()

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='#D2B024')
root.geometry('450x650+900+0')
root.minsize(450, 650)
root.maxsize(450, 650)
main_text = Text(root, bg='#CBCAC5', fg='black', width=30, height=40, state='normal')
main_text.grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=50, padx=9, pady=3)
main_text.delete(1.0, END)
search_ent = Entry(root)
search_ent.grid(row=12, column=2)
if all == True :
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
else :
    main_text.insert(1.0, search(search_ent))
main_text.config(state='disabled')

nomlbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to insert',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=1,column=2)

nom_ent = Entry(root)
nom_ent.grid(row=2, column=2)

num_lbl=Label(root, text='Enter number to insert', bg='#D2B024').grid(row=3, column=2)

num_ent = Entry(root)
num_ent.grid(row=4, column=2)

insert_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='insert', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=insert).grid(row=5, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=50)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=6,column=2)

idlbl=Label(root,text='Enter id to delete',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=7,column=2)
ident=Entry(root)
ident.grid(row=8,column=2)

delete_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='delete', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=delete).grid(row=9, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=10,column=2)

search_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to search',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=11,column=2)

search_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='search', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=lambda: search(search_ent)).grid(row=13, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)

root.mainloop()
```

check `search()` carefully.

Comment: `search_btn = Button(..., command=search(search_ent))` should be `search_btn = Button(..., command=lambda: search(search_ent))`.  BTW passing `search_ent` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly redisigned your code, and it seems to work. I changed the location of the `root`, `search_ent` and `main_text`, now it's before the functions, so there won't be an error.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
global all,root, main_text, num_ent, nom_ent, search_ent

global search_ent
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='#D2B024')
root.geometry('450x650+900+0')
root.minsize(450, 650)
root.maxsize(450, 650)
search_ent = Entry(root)
search_ent.grid(row=12, column=2)

main_text = Text(root, bg='#CBCAC5', fg='black', width=30, height=40, state='normal')
main_text.grid(column=1, row=1, rowspan=50, padx=9, pady=3)
main_text.delete(1.0, END)
def showall():
    all = True
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'select * from blinta'
    cur.execute(request)
    table = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return table
    con.commit()
    con.close()


def delete():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = ' DELETE FROM blinta WHERE id=?'
    cur.execute(request, (ident.get(),))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.configure(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.configure(state='disabled')
    ident.delete(0,END)


def insert():
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = 'insert into blinta (nom,numero) values(?,?)'
    cur.execute(request, (nom_ent.get(), num_ent.get()))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    main_text.config(state='normal')
    main_text.delete(1.0, END)
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
    main_text.config(state='disabled')
    num_ent.delete(0, END)
    nom_ent.delete(0, END)

def search():
    all=False
    con = sqlite3.connect("repertoire.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    request = "select * from blinta where nom = ?"
    noun = search_ent.get()
    args=(noun,)
    cur.execute(request,args)
    selected = str(cur.fetchall()).replace(')', '\n').replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return selected
    con.commit()
    con.close()
insert_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='insert', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=insert).grid(row=5, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=50)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=6,column=2)

idlbl=Label(root,text='Enter id to delete',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=7,column=2)
ident=Entry(root)
ident.grid(row=8,column=2)

delete_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='delete', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=delete).grid(row=9, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)
Label(root,text='_______________________',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=10,column=2)

search_lbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to search',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=11,column=2)

search_btn = Button(relief='flat', fg='black', width=7,
                    text='search', font=("heveltica Bold", 15),
                    command=search).grid(row=13, column=2,
                                         columnspan=2, padx=0)





if all == True :
    main_text.insert(1.0, showall())
else :
    main_text.insert(1.0, search())
main_text.config(state='disabled')

nomlbl=Label(root,text='Enter noun to insert',bg='#D2B024').grid(row=1,column=2)

nom_ent = Entry(root)
nom_ent.grid(row=2, column=2)

num_lbl=Label(root, text='Enter number to insert', bg='#D2B024').grid(row=3, column=2)

num_ent = Entry(root)
num_ent.grid(row=4, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `global search_ent` is not necessary inside `search()` function in OP case.

Comment: yup, this not necessary because i wrore it in the search function and always the same error

Comment: I edited the answer and i posted the full traceback

Comment: This answer will be better if you describe what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line by line and character by character.